# Can I modify/restrict the ATTLIST of an XML DTD to allow for UNIQUE attributes?

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

I don't know if my question is asked correctly. I have an XML document which includes the DTD. I have defined the ATTLISTs and I would like to restrict or modify the DTD that an XML validation will throw an error or will fail, if I have used the same attribute more than once.
My XML document looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- DTD START -->
<!DOCTYPE dtype
[
    <!ELEMENT   dtype   (ea?, eb?, ec, ed?) >
    <!ELEMENT   ea      (data+)             >
    <!ELEMENT   eb      (ee+)               >
    <!ELEMENT   ec      (data+)             >
    <!ELEMENT   ed      (data+)             >
    <!ELEMENT   ee      (data+)             >
    <!ELEMENT   data    (#PCDATA)           >

    <!ATTLIST   ee
                    ef      CDATA   #REQUIRED
    >
    <!ATTLIST   data
                    element CDATA   #REQUIRED
                    value   CDATA   #IMPLIED
                    unit    CDATA   #IMPLIED
                    min     CDATA   #IMPLIED
                    max     CDATA   #IMPLIED
                    avg     CDATA   #IMPLIED
    >
]>
<!-- DTD END -->

<!-- DATA START -->
<dtype>
  <ec>
    <data element="A" unit="counts" min="0.6621" avg="0.6819" max="0.7089" />
    <data element="B" unit="counts" min="0.0463" avg="0.0473" max="0.0503" />
    <data element="C" unit="counts" min="0.1238" avg="0.1264" max="0.1344" />
  </ec>
</dtype>
<!-- DATA END -->

<!-- should be detected as not ok ! -->
<!--
<dtype>
  <ec>
    <data element="A" unit="counts" min="0.6621" avg="0.6819" max="0.7089" />
    <data element="B" unit="counts" min="0.0463" avg="0.0473" max="0.0503" />
    <data element="B" unit="counts" min="0.1238" avg="0.1264" max="0.1344" />
    <data element="C" unit="counts" min="0.1348" avg="0.1644" max="0.1654" />
  </ec>
</dtype>
-->
```

I would like to restrict the DTD to allow for one attribute `element="B"` for example.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only option in DTD is to make the attribute type `ID`. An `ID` must be a `Name` (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name), so this might not work for your data. (It does for the `element` attribute in your sample data though.)

For example, this XML would be invalid because `element="A"` is used twice:

```
<!DOCTYPE dtype
[
    <!ELEMENT   dtype   (ea?, eb?, ec, ed?) >
    <!ELEMENT   ea      (data+)             >
    <!ELEMENT   eb      (ee+)               >
    <!ELEMENT   ec      (data+)             >
    <!ELEMENT   ed      (data+)             >
    <!ELEMENT   ee      (data+)             >
    <!ELEMENT   data    (#PCDATA)           >

    <!ATTLIST   ee
                    ef      CDATA   #REQUIRED
    >
    <!ATTLIST   data
                    element ID   #REQUIRED
                    value   CDATA   #IMPLIED
                    unit    CDATA   #IMPLIED
                    min     CDATA   #IMPLIED
                    max     CDATA   #IMPLIED
                    avg     CDATA   #IMPLIED
    >
]>
<!-- DTD END -->

<!-- DATA START -->
<dtype>
    <ec>
        <data element="A" unit="counts" min="0.6621" avg="0.6819" max="0.7089" />
        <data element="B" unit="counts" min="0.0463" avg="0.0473" max="0.0503" />
        <data element="A" unit="counts" min="0.1238" avg="0.1264" max="0.1344" />
    </ec>
</dtype>
```

Comment: Daniel, thanks for your answer, but I still have a problem. I haven't posted it correctly the first time, but my xml could also look like this `<dtype> <ec> <data element="A" ... /> <data element="B" ... /> <data element="C" ... /> </ec> <ed> <data element="A" ... /> </ed> </dtype>`, which won't be valid -- each `<data element="X" ... />` could appear multiple times in the xml file, but I would like to have **each section** valid. Any hints how to accomplish this?

Comment: @akm - I don't think you'll be able to accomplish this with DTD. I think you could with schema, but I haven't had to do anything like that in a long time. If you'd like, I can try to come up with a schema when I get a little free time.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for your efforts, but I don't think that you need to spend your time on this. I was just thinking/hoping that there is an _easy_ way of accomplishing this. This xml is generated from my SQL server and is needed to transfer information to my calculation engine (_Mathematica_); the xml-generating process should ensure, that there are no duplicates. Maybe, I was just looking for an "insurance" to 100% guarantee it. I will spend more time on the xml-generation and -reading process to have unique attributes. Thanks anyway!